# Null values when retrieving list of items via the soap API

Tags: acumatica

Hi I am running a local instance of acumaticata and accessing my web service endpoint via a windows forms application.

I am calling the getlist method on the Non Stock Items endpoint (this also happens no matter the object im dealing with).  It returns a list of 13 items which is correct but when I drill down all the field values for inventoryid, description etc are all null.  Is there something im missing here, please help.  I have attached a pic of the result I am getting.

[image]

```
    Public Shared Function GetItems() As List(Of NonStockItem)

    Try

        Dim items As Entity() = Client.GetList(New NonStockItem())

        Dim cItems As New List(Of NonStockItem)

        For Each item As NonStockItem In items
            cItems.Add(item)
        Next

        Return cItems

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    Finally

    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: Which endpoint are you using, `Default` or your own?

Comment: My own endpoint

Comment: Does it validate?

Comment: Yes validates fine.  Would it be a permissions thing?

Comment: Yes, it could be.